# Add Custom Field to Billing Address Form on Admin and API - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api

I tried few things but it didn't fully worked.

I need to create a custom field to Billing Address on "Create Order" page on Admin Panel.
And the result of this field should appears on "orders" API.
[image]

All my tests didn't saved the result and didn't show on API.

Anyone could help me with this ?

Thanks.

Comment: You will have to use an extension attributes for that. Check this link. https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/extension_attributes/adding-attributes.html

Comment: The example of the link is for products.

Comment: what is the custom field? when do you want it to be saved? can you describe how the data in this custom field gets created? (is it in the checkout, or is it another part of the system?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Address attribute follow these steps

1. Create your custom attribute in address Entity in your upgrade setup

   ```
   /* @var \Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory */
   $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
   $eav = $customerSetup->getEavConfig();
   $entityTypeId = \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_ADDRESS;
   $customerAddressEntity = $eav->getEntityType($entityTypeId);
   $attributeSetId = $customerAddressEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

   /* @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory $attributeSetFactory */
   $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
   $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

   $code = 'house_no' //YOUR ATTRIBUTE CODE HERE
   if (!$customerSetup->getAttributeId($entityTypeId, $code)) {
           $customerSetup->addAttribute(
               $entityTypeId,
               $code,
               [
                   'type' => 'varchar',
                   'label' => 'House/Flat No',
                   'input' => 'text',
                   'required' => false,
                   'visible' => true,
                   'user_defined' => true,
                   'position' => 10,
                   'system' => 0,
               ]
           );

           $attribute = $eav->getAttribute($entityTypeId, $code);
           $attribute->addData([
               'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
               'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
               'used_in_forms' => [
                   'adminhtml_customer_address',
                   'customer_address_edit',
                   'customer_register_address'
               ],
           ]);
           $attribute->save();
       }
   ```
2. after step 1 your attribute field will start showing on your address section of order.
3. Now to save the attributes values on order placement, create extension attribute file in etc/extension_attributes.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
      <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
         <attribute code="house_no" type="string" />
      </extension_attributes>
   </config>
   ```
4. Now create column in sales_order_address

   ```
   $tableName = $setup->getTable('sales_order_address');
   if ($connection->isTableExists($tableName)) {

       if ($connection->tableColumnExists($tableName, 'house_no') === false) 
       {
           $connection->addColumn(
               $tableName,
               'house_no',
               [
                   'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                   'nullable' => true,
                   'length' => 255,
                   'comment' => 'House No'
               ]
           );
       }
   }
   ```
5. now listen to the event "sales_model_service_quote_submit_before", in your etc/di.xml

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
      <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="extend_sales_quote_submit_before" 
   instance="Vendor\Model\Observer\Sales\Model\ServiceQuoteSubmitBefore"/>
      </event>
   </config>
   ```
6. Create your observer

   ```
   public function execute(Observer $observer)
   {
      $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
      /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
      $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

      try {
         if ($quote->getBillingAddress()) {
           $order->getBillingAddress()->setHouseNo($quote->getBillingAddress()->getHouseNo());
         }

         if (!$quote->isVirtual()) {
           $order->getShippingAddress()->setHouseNo($quote->getShippingAddress()->getHouseNo());
          }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
      }

      return $this;
   }
   ```
7. You will now be able to use this extension attribute in your api too.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Afreen !!!!!!   You're the best.

Comment: You're welcome :) If it worked for you please do accept the answer :) Happy Coding ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Can we do this with orders API to get data of custom attributes of billing address for Magento 2.3.5 p2 ?

If Yes please let me know how would it shows in orders API data.